# Tax Service Recommendation for a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, avalara

I'm developing a cart that needs to calculate tax and am looking for a 3rd party tax service to handle the calculations.

I've used Avalara in another app, but it's somewhat miserable since I have to use the Rjb gem with their java library.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a tax service that works well with rails?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what capabilities for tax calculations are in the library, but ActiveMerchant is an awesome utility for E-Commerce applications. It is well documented and in active development.

Its variety of payment processors might provide you with the calculations you need.

http://www.activemerchant.org/

Answer (score 0):

We use [StrikeIron](http://strikeiron.com/) in our applications.

To be honest, it's *not* the most awesome interface to interact with (unless you really love SOAP). You still have to handle all tax logic in your application, of course, but if you need tax rates broken down by state, county, and city, it should handle your needs fairly well.

This being said, I have yet to find a tax service That Just Ties into Rails™. I'm curious to see what others will have to say in regards to this.